# ajax dropDownList передача двух значении в контроллер

Tags: yii

Пишу на Yii, формирую список заказов с помощью `foreach` c полем статус `dropDownList`, которое при изменении списка отправляет ajax запрос.

Нужно отправить две переменные на сервер:

1. `id` выбранного элемента в спиcке (это работает).
2. `id` записи, статус которой следует изменить (отправляет `id` последней записи, а не ту которую я изменяю с `dropDownList`)

View:

```
<?php
foreach ($orders as $order) {
    echo '<tr>'
    echo '<td class="gray">' . $order['name'] . ' шт.</td>';
    echo '<td class="gray">' . $order['count'] . ' шт.</td>';
    echo '<td class="cost">' . CHtml::dropDownList('status', '', $list, array(
        'ajax' => array(
            'type' => 'POST',
            'url' => CController::createUrl('order/editstatus'),
            'data' => array('id_status' => 'js:this.value',
            'id' => $order['id']), // Это присвоение работает неправильно 
            // для всех записей отправляется id номер последней записи
            // а не ту, которую я изменяю с помощью dropDownList
        )
    )) . '</td>';

  echo '</tr>';
}
?>
```

Буду очень рад помощи

Answer (score 1):

Решено

```
CHtml::dropDownList('status', '', $list, array(
'id' => 'status-'.$order['id'],   
'ajax' => array(
'type' => 'POST',
'url'=>Controller::createUrl('/order/editstatus',array('id'=>$order['id'])), 
'data' => array('id_status' => 'js:this.value'),
)
))
```